# Changing pandas dataframe values based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Is there any way to replace value using dictionary or mapping?
I have dataframe like this:

```
Q14r63: Audi                 Q14r2: BMW                 Q14r1: VW 

Selected                     Not Selected               Not Selected
Not Selected                 Selected                   Selected 
Selected                     Selected                   Not Selected
```

and i have another dataframe which provides codes for the Brands. This df ofcourse can be changed into dictionary also.

```
Brand           Code
Audi             63
BMW              2
VW               1
```

Is there any way to get output where "selected" values in main df can be be changes with car brand?

**Desired Output**

```
Q14r63: Audi               Q14r2: BMW                 Q14r1: VW 

Audi                         NaN                       NaN 
NaN                          BMW                       VW 
Audi                         BMW                       NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract by column `df1['Brand']` columns with `regex` and then set values by mask with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and missing values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
v = df.columns.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(df1['Brand']) + ')', expand=False)
print (v)
Index(['Audi', 'BMW', 'VW'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
m = df.eq('Selected')
print (m)
   Q14r63: Audi  Q14r2: BMW  Q14r1: VW
0          True       False      False
1         False        True       True
2          True        True      False
```

---

```
df = df.mask(m, v[None, :]).where(m)
print (df)
  Q14r63: Audi Q14r2: BMW Q14r1: VW
0         Audi        NaN       NaN
1          NaN        BMW        VW
2         Audi        BMW       NaN
```

Alternative solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, v, np.nan), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
  Q14r63: Audi Q14r2: BMW Q14r1: VW
0         Audi        NaN       NaN
1          NaN        BMW        VW
2         Audi        BMW       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried and it didnt changed anything and also no error :(

Comment: @s_khan92 - There are not some whitespaces in `Brand` column? What return `print (v)` ?

Comment: @s_khan92 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: V is working fine. But m is giving True False values and its only checking if string selected is there

Comment: @s_khan92 - So what is `print (df.stack().unique())` ? There are values `Selected` ? Or different?

Comment: Yes it `array(['Not selected', 'Selected'], dtype=object)`

Comment: @s_khan92 - OK, I change asnwer for test.

Comment: @s_khan92 - If check `v` and `m` it is like my edited answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df[:] = np.where(df.eq('Selected'), df.columns.str.split(': ').str[1], np.nan)

print(df)

 Q14r63: Audi Q14r2: BMW Q14r1: VW
0        Audi       NaN      NaN
1         NaN       BMW       VW
2        Audi       BMW      NaN
```

Comment: I want to use the second dataframe because i have quite big string of column... Is there any way ?

Comment: If the structure of the column names is as above, using the second dataframe just complicates this task? @s_khan92

Comment: Thats the problem.. I made exemplary column.. This is how my column look like `Q14r63: Audi - Sometimes it is hard to remember all. Which of the following car brands do you know of  even if only by name? Please also mark brands you mentioned already in the previous question.`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
brand_map = dict(zip(df2.Code, df2.Brand))
{63: 'Audi', 2: 'BMW', 1: 'VW'}

mapped_values = df.columns.str.extract('Q14r(\d+)')[0].astype(int).map(brand_map)
df[:] = np.where(df == 'Selected', mapped_values, np.nan)

  Q14r63: Audi Q14r2: BMW Q14r1: VW
0         Audi        NaN       NaN
1          NaN        BMW        VW
2         Audi        BMW       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

df1 =

```
Q14r63: Audi                 Q14r2: BMW                 Q14r1: VW 

Selected                     Not Selected               Not Selected
Not Selected                 Selected                   Selected 
Selected                     Selected                   Not Selected
```

df2 =

```
Brand           Code
Audi             63
BMW              2
VW               1
```

You can do something like this,

```
for column in df1.columns: 
    brand = [x for x in df2['Brand'].values if x in column][0]
    df1[column] = df1[column].replace({'Selected': brand, 'Not Selected': 'NaN'})
```