# Changing pandas dataframe values based on dictionary by mapping or mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to replace value using dictionary or mapping?
I have dataframe like this: df

```
Q14r63: Audi                 Q14r2: BMW                 Q14r1: VW 

Selected                     Not Selected               Not Selected
Not Selected                 Selected                   Selected 
Selected                     Selected                   Not Selected
```

and i have another dataframe which provides codes for the Brands. This df ofcourse can be changed into dictionary also. df1

```
Brand           Code
Audi             63
BMW              2
VW               1
```

Is there any way to get output where "selected" values in main df can be be changes with car brand?

**Desired Output**

```
Q14r63: Audi               Q14r2: BMW                 Q14r1: VW 

Audi                         NaN                       NaN 
NaN                          BMW                       VW 
Audi                         BMW                       NaN
```

**So far what i tried:**

```
v = df.columns.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(df1['Brand']) + ')', expand=False)
m = df.eq('Selected')
df = df.mask(m, v[None, :]).where(m)
```

but i  am getting error `ValueError: only one regex group is supported with Index`

***For one dataframe its working fine but other similar dataframe i am getting above mentioned error***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some special regex characters in column, so escape them:

It means change:

```
v = df.columns.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(df1['Brand']) + ')', expand=False)
```

to:

```
import re
v = df.columns.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in df1['Brand']) + ')', expand=False)
```

Comment: Thanks as always but when i run then everything is NaN now

Comment: @s_khan92 - Are data confidental? Because I think it seems data related problem

Comment: Just worked. There were few NaN values in df1 but i am really not sure how it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: The above mentioned code was working fine but now when i am trying on other machine. i am getting this error `ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray`. Can you help?

Comment: @s_khan92 - There is different pandas or python version?

Comment: I didn't check what was in last machine but now i have `1.0.1`

Comment: @s_khan92 - So it working with previous pandas version and now not working? Not easy test without data what is wrong :(

Comment: Oh.. The data is same and i am getting error on this line `df = df.mask(m, v[None, :]).where(m)`

Comment: @s_khan92 - Can you use alternative solution with `np.where`, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60670946/2901002) ?